# Describe the closure of set rational number under metric?

Tags: functional-analysis, algebraic-topology

I have problem with this task.

How do I must describe the closure of ($\mathbb{Z},\rho$) with the metric $ \rho(m,n)=\left |e^{in}-e^{im}   \right |$

I know, that

> The closure of ($\mathbb{R},\rho$) with the metric $ \rho(m,n)=\left |arctg(x)-arctg(y) \right |$ is $ \left ( \left ( -\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}  \right ),  \rho_{L}  \right ) $, where is $\rho_{L}(x,y)=\left | x -y \right |$

How should I do in this metric $\rho(m,n)=\left |e^{in}-e^{im}   \right |$?

Answer (score 3):

If by closure you mean finding a complete metric space in which your set is isometrically embedded then the answer is the circle: $S^1=\{z\in {\Bbb C}:|z|=1\}$. By irrationality of $2\pi$ your points may be identified with distinct points in $S^1$ and they are dense. So the completion may be identified with $S^1$, in which  ${\Bbb Z}$ embeds isometrically as $n\mapsto e^{in}$.

Does this make sense in your context?

Comment: Yes-yes, I should mean finding a complete metric space.

Comment: Thanks you so much!) You solve my problem)